# zsh alias "..."

Tags: shell, zsh

I have an ZSH alias:

```
alias -g ...='../..'
alias -g ....='../../..'
```

When I try to `cd ...`, things work perfectly. I can't, however, use it in a `cp` command: `cp .../file .` fails with `cp: .../file: No such file or directory`.

In addition, trying to use the alias such: `cd .../dir` fails: `cd:cd:10: no such file or directory: .../dir`. Doing the same thing using `cd ...; cd dir` works fine.

From the [zsh-lovers](http://grml.org/zsh/zsh-lovers.html) page:

> Global aliases can be used anywhere in the command line. Example:

```
$ alias -g C='| wc -l'
$ grep alias ~/.zsh/* C
443
```

The [ZSH Introduction](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Intro/intro_8.html) also says that global aliases are substituted anywhere in the command line.

Why aren't my aliases being used as I thought they should be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe the reason is that the '...' in '.../file' is not space/boundry delimited?
e.g In the zsh-lovers example, 'C' is preceded by a space.

From another SU question I found the following that might help:
[nicoulaj / dotfiles : rationalize-dots](https://github.com/nicoulaj/dotfiles/blob/7a37acd50401a235d6dec6327cd5b2224d704b72/zsh/comp.d/ZLE/rationalize-dots)

Comment: this is my immediate thought, it's not seeing an alias, it's seeing `.../file` If you aliased C like then and then did `mv myClass ~/src/` and it expanded the alias, that'd be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

In contrast to aliases, [static named directory](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/zsh-common/zshexpn.1.en.html#Static_named_directories) `~...` will expand to `../..` inside paths, if defined as

```
$ hash -d ...=../..
```

For example,

```
$ cd /usr/share/zsh
$ readlink -m ~...
/usr
```